# Liberty Farm while uploading .wlapp file it says Server is not reachable

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

[image]

[image]

> My ServerFarm.xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Farm xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="FarmSchema.xsd">
    <LibertyNode Hostname="192.168.0.98" ServerID ="server1_farm" AdminPass="demo" AdminUser="demo" JMXPortNumber="9443"   />
    <LibertyNode Hostname="192.168.0.149" ServerID ="server2_farm" AdminPass="admin" AdminUser="admin" JMXPortNumber="9443"   />
</Farm>
```

> My server.xml File

```
<application id="worklight" name="worklight" location="project2.war" type="war">
   <application-bnd>
        <security-role name="worklightadmin">
            <user name="demo"/>
        </security-role>
    </application-bnd>
     <classloader delegation="parentLast">
        <privateLibrary id="worklightlib_worklight">
            <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/worklight/lib" includes="worklight-jee-library.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="${wlp.install.dir}/lib" includes="com.ibm.ws.crypto.passwordutil_*.jar"/>
        </privateLibrary>
        <fileset dir="${wlp.install.dir}/lib" includes="com.ibm.ws.crypto.passwordutil_*.jar"/>
        </privateLibrary>
    </classloader>
</application>
```

> com.worklight.common.util.jmx.LibertyFarmRuntimeMBeanHandler E Exception sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed

Kindly advice.

Comment: Please provide context about what you're trying to accomplish and where.  Is this running on Bluemix or is it on-prem? There's not even a question associated with the post.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you have incorrectly imported the certificate to the keystore. You may follow the instructions in the following post to resolve your issue: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/answers/211204/view.html

Answer (score 0):

Everything i did well. i have miss to exchange the certificate in both servers.
well i have followed [IBM MobileFirst 7.1 Configuring a server farm](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_server_farm_setup.html). Let try this like i think it will be hopeful for every one.